# How to query three columns and total only one column?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

[image: What i really want to see!]I have a table called Library, I need all columns such as title, author and type. I only want to count all the titles.

I have tried this:

```sql
SELECT A.TITLE || ' - ' || A.Author || ' - ' || A.Type AS Title, Count(TITLE) 
From Library A 
group by title
```

This only gives me Title and Count, I want to see the authors and type as well.

And this:

```sql
SELECT TITLE, AUTHOR, TYPE COUNT(TITLE)  
FROM LIBRARY  
GROUP BY TITLE
```

I couldn't get a word table to post. So I added as image. This is sample data with output.

Sample data with output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results for that data. At a guess, the problem is that you're not specifying all relevant non-aggregated columns in the `group by`, but that should produce an error and not some weird result as you seem to imply.

Comment: `I couldn't get a word table to post` - google "word to markdown", there are plenty of options, from online file converters to installable plugins for MS Word itself. I don't know which are good or not.

Comment: I am not sure why I would use word? This is firebird sql.

Answer (score 1):

for `handy library manager` use following query

```
SELECT A.TITLE, A.AUTHOR,A.TYPE,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LIBRARY B WHERE B.TYPE= A.TYPE)
FROM LIBRARY A
```

or use

```
SELECT A.TITLE, A.AUTHOR, A.TYPE,B.Total
FROM LIBRARY A 
JOIN (select TYPE,COUNT(*) AS Total from LIBRARY GROUP BY TYPE) B 
ON A.TYPE = B.TYPE
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Displays nothing like mine does. arggg

Comment: @Horsebkridr I added another method, test to see if you get the desired answer.

Comment: something is wrong. nothing is working. I am using a database called handy library manager. I can make my own custom views. I can get it to work separately but not together.

Comment: That is giving the totals on every line. Anyway to get the total only on the last title.

Comment: IT IS WORKING THOUGH! I APPRECIATE YOU!

Comment: So those "2" in count column are correct values? Are them really?
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=bfb3ecf45379e1341bdba6563acf676c

Comment: YES THERE IS TWO MAGAZINES AND 39 BOOKS. THE TOTAL IS DISPLAYED ON EVERYLINE OF EVERY BOOK AND MAGAZINE.

Comment: @Horsebkridr please look at the data following the hyperlink in my comment above, there is no any books and magazines at all there, try to understand the point i am making with my data, try to understand why i was composing exactly that data set..

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your mind clear WHAT EXACTLY do you count. For example, "Over the hills and far away" - there are at least three (maybe more) songs with this name (title) but different authors and centuries and lyrics (content).

So you have to DECIDE for youself WHAT that is specifically that you do count, what set of data exactly makes a book identity, an invariant.

- TITLES only regardless of author?
- Or AUTHOR+TITLE tuples?
- Or even some more details maybe? for example the same novel of a same author can be published in different years and even by different publishers, and while those are all the same book for a reader, those are different books for a stock keeper.

And after you made your mind (which is not easy) you have to make sample tables that try to "break the rules". If you made one ideal set of data and one ideal query and got good results, it does NOT mean that "program works". It would only mean so if the results are still good for ANY initial data, including data sets made to compromise the program and to confuse it.

The following queries would all work over your table and would all return "good results", but those might be different results. Or same. Depending on the source data.

```
SELECT TITLE, TYPE COUNT(TITLE)  
FROM LIBRARY  
GROUP BY TITLE

SELECT TITLE, TYPE COUNT(1)  
FROM LIBRARY  
GROUP BY TITLE

SELECT TITLE, AUTHOR, COUNT(1)  
FROM LIBRARY  
GROUP BY TITLE, AUTHOR

SELECT TITLE, LIST(AUTHOR), COUNT(1)  
FROM LIBRARY  
GROUP BY TITLE

SELECT TITLE, MIN(AUTHOR), MAX(AUTHOR), COUNT(1)  
FROM LIBRARY  
GROUP BY TITLE
```

All of those queries are correct, and all of them might return the same data on simplistic source table ("program works"), and still them would return different results for more diverse source data, that tends to happen in real life.

And, there is no way you can choose which of those queries produce the results you wish, before you make the problem clear to yourself and then to us.

Andthen you would have to make data `CONSTRAINT`s for your tables, like `PRIMARY KEY`s and `UNIQUE INDEX`es which make inserting wrong data into the table impossible, and then you would have also to create regular `INDEX`es that make searching (selecting) faster, but would make changing (insert/update/delete) slower.

Because for a table that has no indexes some trivial queries even with just as few as one thousand books might result in a million or billion of searches and became unbearably slow. If it works with satisfactory for a tiny set 10 books, it does not mean it still would work for a small set of 1000 books, less so for a middle-sized set of 100K-1M books. Been there, done that; learn from my past experience, or you would have to learn from yours...

Some examples:

> ```
> select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') as version
>      , rdb$character_set_name
> from rdb$database;
> ```
>
> ```
> VERSION | RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME                                                                                                      
> :------ | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 3.0.5   | UTF8
> ```

> ```
> create table library(
>   title varchar(20)
>   , author varchar(20)
>   , kind varchar(20)
>   -- , publisher varchar(20)  -- does htis make difference or not ???
>   -- , year integer  -- does this make difference or not ???
>   -- , ISBN_code varchar (40) -- does this ???
>   
> --  primary key(title)  -- is this correct?
> --  primary key(author, title) -- or is THIS correct
> --  primary key (ISBN_code)  -- or maybe this is correct ???
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into library 
> select 'Sun and Moon', 'Johanne Arke', 'manuscript' from RDB$Database 
> union all
> select 'Sun and Moon', 'Noah', 'clay table' from RDB$Database 
> union all
> select 'Origin of Species', 'Noah', 'manuscript' from RDB$Database 
> union all
> select 'My Holy War', 'Johanne Arke', 'newspaper' from RDB$Database
> ```

> 

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from library -- check our data WAS entered actually
> ```
>
> ```
> TITLE             | AUTHOR       | KIND      
> :---------------- | :----------- | :---------
> Sun and Moon      | Johanne Arke | manuscript
> Sun and Moon      | Noah         | clay table
> Origin of Species | Noah         | manuscript
> My Holy War       | Johanne Arke | newspaper
> ```

> ```
> -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68535052/976391  option #1
> SELECT A.TITLE, A.AUTHOR, A.KIND, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LIBRARY B WHERE B.KIND = A.KIND)
> FROM LIBRARY A
> ```
>
> ```
> TITLE             | AUTHOR       | KIND       | COUNT
> :---------------- | :----------- | :--------- | ----:
> Sun and Moon      | Johanne Arke | manuscript |     2
> Sun and Moon      | Noah         | clay table |     1
> Origin of Species | Noah         | manuscript |     2
> My Holy War       | Johanne Arke | newspaper  |     1
> ```

> ```
> -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68535052/976391  option #2
> SELECT A.TITLE, A.AUTHOR, A.KIND, B.Total
> FROM LIBRARY A 
> JOIN (select KIND ,COUNT(*) AS Total from LIBRARY GROUP BY KIND) B 
> ON A.KIND = B.KIND
> ```
>
> ```
> TITLE             | AUTHOR       | KIND       | TOTAL
> :---------------- | :----------- | :--------- | ----:
> Sun and Moon      | Johanne Arke | manuscript |     2
> Sun and Moon      | Noah         | clay table |     1
> Origin of Species | Noah         | manuscript |     2
> My Holy War       | Johanne Arke | newspaper  |     1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT TITLE, AUTHOR, COUNT(1)  
> FROM LIBRARY  
> GROUP BY TITLE, AUTHOR
> ```
>
> ```
> TITLE             | AUTHOR       | COUNT
> :---------------- | :----------- | ----:
> My Holy War       | Johanne Arke |     1
> Origin of Species | Noah         |     1
> Sun and Moon      | Johanne Arke |     1
> Sun and Moon      | Noah         |     1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT TITLE, MIN(AUTHOR), MAX(AUTHOR), LIST(AUTHOR), COUNT(1)  
> FROM LIBRARY  
> GROUP BY TITLE
> ```
>
> ```
> TITLE             | MIN          | MAX          | LIST                      | COUNT
> :---------------- | :----------- | :----------- | :------------------------ | ----:
> My Holy War       | Johanne Arke | Johanne Arke | Johanne Arke              |     1
> Origin of Species | Noah         | Noah         | Noah                      |     1
> Sun and Moon      | Johanne Arke | Noah         | Johanne Arke,Noah         |     2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=bfb3ecf45379e1341bdba6563acf676c)*

Comment: I think the problem is because i am in a program that was design from firebird 2.5.5 and this code is not coming directly from the console. But it is working with that  Meysam Asad provided.

Comment: This is a program call handy library manager. So what might work on someone working with in the console, will not work in Handy library manager because of its premade software. Attached is the only thing the company suggested. There was  a price field that holds numerical data. So i used it by putting a 1 in every title under Price field (renamed it to copies) and it totals by type that way.  I only want TITLE field to be counted. 2 copies are rare, but even if the 1 is entered into the PRICE/ COPIES field it totals at the end and grouped by type.  i can't see the code though.

Comment: "working with that Meysam Asad provided" - is there proof it would still correctly work with any other data ? Is formula `A+2 = 2xA` correct, because it is working with example database `A=2` ?

Comment: `I only want TITLE field to be counted` then that is what you have to do, `SELECT TITLE,  COUNT(1) FROM LIBRARY GROUP BY TITLE`

Comment: The problem is that this is a software using fThe problem is that this is a software using firebird 2.5.5. They have seperate parts to input custom codes using the firebird language. The above results is what i wanted. The company gave me this code for that SELECT A.TITLE, A.AUTHOR, A.TYPE, B.Total FROM LIBRARY A JOIN (select TITLE, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL from LIBRARY GROUP BY TITLE) B ON A.TITLE = B.TITLE Then after hitting Print i had to check Total . see the bottom picture for the screen shot of the Handy Library Manager. Thanks for everybody's help. I am learning a lot!